# In DynamoDB, which is faster? Querying by Id or by a secondary index attribute?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a DynamoDB table where I need to query on two different attributes, sometimes by one, sometimes by the other one, but never by both at the same time.

Let's say I have an attribute A and attribute B, other attributes are irrelevant here.

I'm thinking of design this table with the Hash Key being the attribute A and a GSI being attribute B.
This way I always perform `query` instead of `scan`.

Now a question comes to my mind, which query is faster, on Attribute A (which is the Id) or on the Attribute B (GSI)?

If there is some difference I could switch, letting B as Id and A as GSI.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, interesting question, it is very unlikely to have different performance - generally in any database. "Primary key" and "index" is in all databases I know the same structure with same performance. Keep in mind that the `Hash Key` has to be unique while GSI not

Comment: Hi @RaymondNijland I've already read, many times by the way, but this kind of performance comparison is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GSI is an actual DynamoDB table with all the main table data copied.

It can be more efficient if you [project](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Projection.html) only the attributes you need.

It may be less efficient considering hash keys are not unique and you may end up iterating on those results to find the desired one.